# making a blog using php

Tags: php

I am new to php and wanted to make a blog using php where every one can see the contents posted in the site but another administrator page should be there which can edit, add or delete posts

How can i code a page like that? What are the logics required?

Comment: Hi, I'd like a site like Amazon.com.  Please post the source code. k tnks bai.

Comment: Don’t be a hater.... Chill out we ALL started somewhere

Comment: This is potentially a very interesting question, just phrased a little poorly.

@Bloggermonster: I think you would have got a much better reaction to this questions if you had, after explaining what you are doing, asked something like: "What are the issues that I should consider around this?"

Answer (score 8):

no1: If you just need a blog software, don't write it yourself, there are tons of free services and applications you can use or adapt

no2: If you want to do this because you want to learn php, go ahead!

no3: Best way of doing this is following a tutorial! 10 seconds of googling is enough and will help you much more than posting a question like that here: http://www.google.ee/search?q=tutorial+php+blog

Answer (score 3):

There are [lots](http://nettuts.com/news/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/) [of](http://www.visionmasterdesigns.com/2008/07/tutorial-creating-a-content-management-system-using-phpmysql/) [tutorials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/os-dw-os-php-blog-i.html) for this sort of venture [around the internet](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&hs=IGd&q=code+a+blog+in+php+tutorial&btnG=Search&meta=).

I think It may be a bit too much to write in a single answer here.. You're best to choose one of these tutorials or find a book that uses building a blog as a means for learning more about PHP.

Answer (score 2):

At this stage you have 2 choices.

1. Learn some basic PHP (which would include databasing, web server management, safe form handling, html, javascript, css etc.) And then implement some very basic blog which would suit your purposes.
2. Use a prepackaged product like Wordpress, Drupal, or one of the hundreds available. You could perhaps modify it slightly to suit your needs and you would learn PHP in the process.

Answer (score 2):

The workflow that you're looking for is quite simple, with just 2 layers.

- Create/Update/Delete items
- View Items

I'd direct you to [nettut's excellent walkthrough on the subject](http://nettuts.com/news/how-to-create-an-object-oriented-blog-using-php/), which goes through all stages of implementation (creation of database objects, queries, etc). It leaves out the beautifying process (it's styleless) which only means that you'll have an even greater amount of freedom. It also tries to conform to an object oriented design, while keeping it simple to avoid making people disencouraged (a blog site *can* be a large project).

If you're feeling less adventurous [they also have an excellent article on making a simple shoutbox](http://nettuts.com/php/create-a-basic-shoutbox-with-php-and-sql/)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Internet tutorials are great. You are going to want to consider two main things:

1. How you store the data (the posts people write)
2. How you present this to the user.

**Data**:

You could consider databases but this is probably overkill for a learning excersise. Probably simple text files, perhaps one per entry (with a unique naming scheme), or structured XML to store the posts info. You will need to think about indexing each entry in some way so that it can easily be recovered. You will need to consider poerformance implications of your choice, such as file-reads etc. This will not be a problem in a small test site, but you should think about what happens of you had thousands of users as part of the excersise.

**Presentation**

You will need to look at some css and html to get make displaying the content easily configurable. Think about what componants you want to display, things such as a blog "entry", which you can then programatically put into the html when you serve a page as many times as you need.